# How can I find WHY the OpenXml SDK tool won't open a file

Tags: openxml-sdk

When the OpenXml SDK tool fails to open a file, saying that the (PPTX in this case) is incorrect, is there a way to find from it exactly what it is unhappy with?

And/or is there another tool that can list out what is wrong?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @AdamShakhabov Yes. Write a little program that uses the SDK to open the file and have it list out all errors it encounters doing so.